# Are pure function calls optimized in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-optimization

Today I was wondering something and couldn't find the answer anywhere: let's say I have a pure function and I'm calling it 2 times in a row with the same parameters, will there be any compiler optimization (or something like that) that will recognize that the function is pure and will cache the result in some ways?

For example, in that code:

```
const myString = "a,b,c";
console.log(myString.split(","));
console.log(myString.split(","));
```

Is there anything that will cache the result of the first `myString.split(",")` and re-use it the second time? I'm assuming that not, because it would require to determine that the function is pure, which could be cumbersome if that function lazy loads something for example, or if the function calls other functions etc...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thing. It's theoretically possible *however*, cache is also one of the hardest problems in computer science, so I suspect no current JS engine will do that automatically. Consider this - *should* the cache me retained? For how long? Would cache actually introduce a memory leak if used in a large loop? Would it lead to unpredictable behaviour (crashing or increased GC runs)?

Comment: As you already pointed out, this would be very hard to implement. But there's a much better reason to avoid code like this: maintainability (in particular the DRY principle).

Comment: In addition, as you said it requires determining whether a function is pure which, in the general case, is about as easy as solving the halting problem.

Comment: "Cache is one of the hardest problems in computer science."  Really?  And I thought it was naming things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey :) we both know they are the top two. Alongside off-by-one problems.

Comment: In any case, this is a memoization problem.  Try a Google Search for that.

Comment: `String.prototype.split = () => console.log("oops");`